# Typescript extending dojo classes

Tags: typescript, dojo

I have created what I think should allow me to invoke methods declared by _WidgetBase on an instance of a class in Typescript. The problem is, the compiler doesn't see the relationship between the pieces I've declared. I must be doing something wrong.

I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../node_modules/dojo-typings/dojo/1.11/dojo.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../../../node_modules/dojo-typings/dijit/1.11/dijit.d.ts" />

declare namespace com {
  namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
      namespace web {
        namespace components {
          namespace form {
            interface ModelObjectMainFormView extends dijit._Widget, dijit._TemplatedMixin, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin, dojo.Evented {
              on(type: string | dojo.ExtensionEvent, func: dojo.EventListener | Function): dojo.WatchHandle;
              emit(type: string | dojo.ExtensionEvent, ...events: any[]): boolean;
            }

            interface ModelObjectFormViewConstructor {
              new (args: Array<any>);
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
/// <reference path="index.d.ts" />

declare module 'com/foo/bar/web/components/form/ModelObjectMainFormView' {
  type ModelObjectMainFormView = com.foo.bar.web.components.form.ModelObjectMainFormView;
  const ModelObjectMainFormView: com.foo.bar.web.components.form.ModelObjectFormViewConstructor;
  export = ModelObjectMainFormView;
}
```

and:

```
import declare = require("dojo/_base/declare");
import ModelObjectMainFormView = require("com/foo/bar/web/components/form/ModelObjectMainFormView");

class TSModelObjectMainFormView {
  templateString: string;
  inherited: (args: Object) => any;

  constructor(args?: any) {
    if (args && args.templateString) {
      this.templateString = args.templateString;
      this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  }
}

var exp = declare("com.foo.bar.web.components.form.TSModelObjectMainFormView", [ModelObjectMainFormView], new TSModelObjectMainFormView());
export = exp;
```

and:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="dojo/text!com/foo/bar/web/workItems/configuration/forms/templates/ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView.html" name="template" />
import * as aspect from 'dojo/aspect';
import * as lang from 'dojo/_base/lang';
import GridView = require('com/foo/bar/web/components/grid/GridView');
import * as TSModelObjectMainFormView from '../../../components/form/TSModelObjectMainFormView';
import { ConfigurationWorkItemController } from '../ConfigurationWorkItemController';
let template: string;

export class ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView extends TSModelObjectMainFormView {
  summaryGrid: GridView;

  constructor(args: any) {
    super(lang.mixin(args, {templateString: template}));
  }

  postCreate(): void {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.summaryGrid.setModel(this.getSummaryGridModel());

    this.own(aspect.after(ret,"updateProperty", lang.hitch(this,function(n,v,refresh){
        if(refresh){
          this.summaryGrid.refresh();
        }
      }),true));  
    }
  }
}
```

This is not a complete piece of code, but it shows the problem. the call to this.own in the source just above fails to compile. Property 'own' does not exist on type ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView.

Why can the compiler not see that ConfigurationWorkItemMainFormView is extending TSModelObjectMainFormView which extends _Widget which extends _WidgetBase which extends Destroyable which declares 'own'?

Typescript version 2.7.2.

Much appreciate any insights.